ChEMBL API usage results in "sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed"
I use ChEMBL's chembl_webresource_client. However, yesterday, and today all my requests, even basic from GitHub document are returning:

sqlite3.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

Can this error be caused on my end, and if so, how to battle it? If not, how can I find other ways to access this DB?
import pandas as pd 
from chembl_webresource_client.new_client import new_client 


activities = new_client.activity.filter(target_chembl_id__in=['CHEMBL5552','CHEMBL1075195']  
                                        , pchembl_value__gte=5                               
                                        , assay_type='B'                                   
                                       ).only(['target_chembl_id', 'target_pref_name', 'parent_molecule_chembl_id' 
                                                               ,'molecule_chembl_id','molecule_pref_name', 'pchembl_value'])

act_df = pd.DataFrame(activities)
act_df

I've tried changing input, instead of activity use .molecule method and then tried to use exemplary scripts from documentation but to no avail.

Issue was in corrupted cache, removing it sovled (rm ~/.chembl_ws_client__0.10.9)
